# Separate date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following line of code and would like to display the time also but add a text between the date and time:

```
Code:
'<p class="postedon" >Posted on ' + val.date.substring(0,10)
```

As seen, i used a substring to only display the date but with the substring this is what is displayed on my mobile app

2013-09-01 16:20

What I want to achieve is: date + at + time

2013-09-01 at 16:20

Comment: Can you clarify whether the language you're working with is java or javascript?

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Those are two different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java  , better way is

```
String dateString = "2013-09-01 16:20";
String[] split = dateString .split(s);
System.out.println(split[0]+" at "+split[1]);
```

`0th` element is your date string and `1th` element is time string.

If you are confused with java and javascript  then

```
var dateString = "2013-09-01 16:20";
var split = dateString .split(s);
consol.log(split[0]+" at "+split[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks but since I am doing a json api call, how would this help.

Comment: @IsaacBassey  what is the String you are getting from API ?

Comment: This is what I am getting: 2013-09-02 15:04:50

Comment: So what is the issue now? Facing issue with time string?

Comment: If so please again split or use substring on split[1]

Comment: Hi Suresh, this is what I did for it to work but I am now trying to style that bit separately:

    output += '<p class="postxt">Posted on <span class="posval">' + val.date.substring(0,10) + val.date.substring(10) +'</span>' ;

Comment: @IsaacBassey So what's the issue ?How can I help you ?

Comment: sorry mate, I am still new to jquery so was thinking how do I then add css for just the time bit. thanks

Comment: I see why yours wasn't working as expected, the (s) isn't defined so I replaced the (s) with (' '):

    var split = dateString .split(' ');

Answer (score 2):

This was my final working code:

```
var dateString = val.date; // this display my blog post date e.g. "2013-09-02 15:04:50"
var split = dateString.split(' ');

output += '<div class="postxt">Posted on <span class="posval">' + split[0] + '</span> at <span class="posval">' + split[1] + '</span></div>';
```

Hope this helps others